# should I use it or static_cast<void*> then static_cast<myType*> to avoid reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++, casting, reinterpret-cast, static-cast

I have seen people suggest using `static_cast<SomeType*>(static_cast<void*>(p))` rather than reinterpret casting.

I don't understand why this is better, can someone explain?

For the sake of argument here is an example scenario where reinterpret_cast is needed:

```
DWORD lpNumberOfBytes;
ULONG_PTR lpCompletionKey;
LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped;
GetQueuedCompletionStatus(myHandle, &lpNumberOfBytes, &lpCompletionKey, &lpOverlapped, 0);
if(lpCompletionKey == myCustomHandlerKey){
    auto myObject = reinterpret_cast<MyObject*>(lpOverlapped);  //i know this is really a MyObject
}
```

This is what I have heard suggested:

```
auto myObject = static_cast<MyObject*>(static_cast<void*>(lpOverlapped));
```

**Edit:** I origionally started my question with <del>In the comments section "asdf" suggests using static_cast instead of reinterpret_cast here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/02/04/challenge-vulnerable-code.aspx</del> but in retrospect the fact that my question came from there is irrelevant.

Comment: reinterpret_cast is almost always implementation defined and what happens isn't always guaranteed to be portable.

Comment: @PlasmaHH That’s a bit misleading. `reinterpret_cast` has very well defined semantics, they are just very limited. But in this case the semantics seem to be covered (I say this without having looked at the code, based on OP’s statement of `lpOverlapped`). But reading asdf’s comment is an entirely different case.

Comment: When you are casting from a pointer type to another pointer type, `reinterpret_cast` is specified in terms of `static_cast<cv ToType*>(static_cast<cv void*>(p))` in C++11. They are both the same.

Comment: On another note, if you wanted to make sure the conversion is safe you can use [something like this](http://ideone.com/UHC8Zk) and then use `pointer_cast<MyObject>(lpOverlapped)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

§5.2.10 describes the legal mappings that `reinterpret_cast` can perform, and specifies that “No other conversion can be performed”.

The conversion relevant for your example is /7:

> A pointer to an object can be explicitly converted to a pointer to a different object type. When a prvalue `v` of type “pointer to `T1`” is converted to the type “pointer to *cv* `T2`”, the result is `static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))` **if both `T1` and `T2` are standard-layout types … and the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`**. [emphasis mine]

The result of the conversions of any *other* pointer to object types is “unspecified”.<sup>1</sup>

This is one of two reasons why `reinterpret_cast` is dangerous: its conversion is only well-defined for a subset of pointer to object types, and compilers usually offer *no* diagnostics about accidental misuse.

The second reason is that the compiler doesn’t even check whether the mapping you are trying to perform is legal in the first place, and which of the many (semantically completely different) mappings is going to be performed.

Better to be explicit and tell the compiler (and the reader) *which* the intended conversion is that you want to perform. That said, asdf’s comment isn’t quite correct, because not *all* conversions that you might want to perform via `reinterpret_cast` are equivalent to using `static_cast<void*>` followed by a `static_cast` to the target type.

---

<sup>1</sup> Aside: In a nutshell (and slightly simplified), a [“standard layout type”](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout) is a type (or array of type) which doesn’t have virtual functions or mixed member visibility, and all its members and bases are also standard layout. The [alignment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof) of a type is a restriction on the addresses in memory at which it may be located. For example, many machines require that `double`s are aligned at addresses divisible by 8.

Comment: +1 for quoting standard and explaining most important bits... I'd give +2 for listing and explaining all individual requirements if you did and I could. see, even I forgot alignment in my answer for example.

Comment: When is the double `static_cast` defined outside of the case where reinterptret is defined and the identity double cast?

Comment: @Yakk I’m not exactly sure what you mean but if I understand you correctly, the double `static_cast` `via `void*` is *more restrictive* rather than more general than a `reinterpret_cast`. *That* is the reason for preferring it: its semantics are thus clearer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph `reinterpret_cast` says "if *condition*, then it is equivalent to `static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(X))`"  Now, that double-`static_cast`, if written out explicitly, is valid if **either** *condition*, or if `X` is a `T*` (even if the condition does not hold!).  Are there any other cases for which that double static cast results in defined behavior?

Comment: @Yakk to be honest I have no idea. Before reading the section referenced in my answer I would actually have said that this cast was illegal because I thought that after casting to `void*` the only legal cast was back to the original type. I still think this is true for non-pointer `T` but now I’m not sure any more.

Answer (score 2):

`asdf` explained it quite well, even if concisely in the linked post.

> because the compiler doesn't know CustomImage derives from Image at
>   this point in the program.

Personally I can't be bothered to download rubbish from msdn just to dig in and answer the question. After all it is a coding challenge, you are supposed to figure it out.

My rules for casting in C++ are:

1. use C++ style casts `xx_cast<T*>` and not C-style `(T*)`, for *explicit is better than implicit.*
2. only use reinterpret cast when you really really mean it.
3. if you do use `reinterpret_cast<T*>` make sure that cast/uncast are exact mirror, e.g.:

.

```
T* obj = ...;
void* tmp = reinterpret_cast<void*> obj;
T* ref = reinterpret_cast<T*> tmp;  // T* obj --> T* ref
```

Here, you must make sure that `obj` and `ref` are same exact type, including const qualifiers, class derivation, alignment, type of memory (embedded), absolutely anything you can think of.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "application/reapplication must be exact mirror"?  Do you mean the spec *assures* that we should have `obj == ref`?  Or do you mean we ourselves should be careful to use `reinterpret_cast` only for types such that `obj == ref` and any other usages might lead to an undefined or implementation-defined behavior?